# How to navigate between two different tables in VB.NET (Access database)

Tags: database, vb.net, ado.net, dataset, tableadapter

In my VB.Net program I need to add the table "order" and "line of order".
If the first order is selected, I can only navigate the line(s) of order that is linked to the first order. I have no_order in my "line of order" table, so if it's the the first order, I need to only be able to navigate between the line of order with the value "1" in no_order.

In my program I already have the table "product" that I can navigate, delete, add, and modify. How much more complicated is this, or different to do what I just mentioned above? How should I go about doing this? I'm not sure where to start. Would it help if I posted my code from the "product" table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are selecting orders from a dropdown and want lines of order on the same form then you should try this.

1. Bind the order dropdown on formLoad or PageLoad and set `enable=false` to 2nd dropdown (i.e of lines of code)
2. Bind the 2nd dropdown on 1st dropdown's selectedIndexChanged event with the query something like this.

> 

```
  /* ConnectionObject, CommandObject and all that  */

  select * from LinesofCode where no_order=@no_order
  cmd.parameter.addwithValue("no_order",dropdown1st.selectedValue);
```